# copyright and trademark symbols in mono winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

I am looking to potentially port over a windows .NET application to linux and while most of it works, I am having issues getting the trademark and copyright symbols to render correctly in winform controls.  In our code we have two constants in our code for each of the symbols...

```
// <summary>
/// The copyright symbol
/// </summary>
public const string COPYRIGHT = "\u00AE";

/// <summary>
/// The trademark symbol
/// </summary>
public const string TRADEMARK = "\u2122";
```

Any thoughts on how to have these rendered as more than a "?" in the control texts?

Comment: nope, just tried it and it's a no go

Comment: tried to change the encoding?

Comment: As it turns out, I noticed that someone had gone in and manually entered the symbols into the source file instead of using the constants, so that a big whoops on my part.  Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0):

After investigation it appears that after having manually changed the automatically generated winforms code to include constants (ie: "MyProduct" + Constants.COPYRIGHT), visual studio had changed it back to "MyProduct(C)" which was failing to load the copyright symbol.  So I had to switch it back to using a constant and everything is working as expected.  Now how to stop Visual Studio for man-handling my strings....